# User Control events when "splitting" a XAML file

Tags: wpf

Several people have asked how to split up large XAML files into smaller more manageable or readable chunks.     In my case I have a XAML file with 10 tabs and each tab has a lot of complex controls.     So the XAML file for this is huge and hard to read.

The "standard" answer for this seems to be User Controls.

I'm sure this is a real noob question, but if all you're trying to do is split up the XAML file, how do you do it without splitting up the C#, too?    When you create a WPF user control Visual Studio creates a new XAML file **plus** new code-behind file to go with it and handle the events.

What I really wanted was the equivalent of a "C# partial" directive for XAML so I could just split it up among multiple files but have the events handled in one place.     How close can I get to that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could probably extract a lot of things like your `Converters`, `Brushes`, or even `TabItem.Template` into a separate `ResourceDictionary` file, and just import the `ResourceDictionary` at the top of your XAML file instead of using UserControls

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do as you describe (to allow multiple xaml files to share the same c# code).  Also from what you describe there isn't an *easy* way to quickly abstract that code without having to make some changes.  Since wpf events are typically driven by commands, the best solution would probably be to change your events to fire commands rather than putting the logic within the actual event handler itself, then calling it from the user control would be trivial.

But before you go changing all your code, you may be able to abstract out a lot of the long stuff using styles, which are way easier to abstract out and shouldn't mess with your events.  So if you notice repeating how things are setup across lots of controls, just declare all of it as a style and you can move it into a resource dictionary elsewhere to remove some clutter.

To elaborate a bit you can use styles not just to stop repetition, but also to abstract out how you define your controls (much like you are trying to use user controls for, you can also define events there).  For example...

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="Tab1Style">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!--Note even if this style is defined in a resource file the 
                        events will still be tied to the class of the control
                        using the style-->
                    <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" />
                    <Button Click="Button_Click_2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then simplify one of your tabitems to simply...

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource Tab1Style}" />
</TabControl>
```

If you really have your heart set on user controls you could also just route all the events out.  Something like this...

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Button Click="OnClick"/>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ButtonClick = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "ButtonClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl1));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ButtonClickHandler
    {
        add { AddHandler(ButtonClick, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ButtonClick, value); }
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(UserControl1.ButtonClick);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```
<Window>
    <local:UserControl1 ButtonClickHandler="Button_Click" />
</Window>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Click");
}
```

(like I said lots of plumbing code)

Comment: I've already used styles to take care of the cases where there's a lot of repetition.     This is a project where I'm essentially rewriting an old VB6 app in .Net/WPF.    The big tab control controls a big complex piece of industrial machinery with hundreds of settings and options.

Comment: I'm new at user controls, but your answer implies a huge difference between a user control and one supplied by the framework.   I can take a stock button and plop it down in my app and handle click events in my app.  But if I create a "button" user control and plop it down in my app, the click events will be handled in the user-control's code-behind, but not in my app? Is that right?  So what good are user controls?   Would I be better off with custom controls?

Comment: @user316117 You could handle the click event from the app, but it would require a little plumbing for every event, custom controls would just make things more difficult.  Give me a little while and I will elaborate on my answer.